# xcode 7 layout error when viewing info.plist

Tags: xcode, xcode7, info.plist

I'm unable to edit some values of info.plist in Xcode. Can I access it in any other way than opening it in external editor?

[image: Layout bug]

Comment: What values are you unable to edit?

Comment: Are your double-clicking on the Value field?

Comment: the overlaying values, it's just being rendered while the clicking is being handled by the other sections like "Document Types", "Exported UITs" etc